# The last time I [...] was back to January. "in" or "back to"

Tags: grammaticality

Somehow my brain came up with the sentence: `The last time I [verb] was back to October.`

I want to emphasize it was long time ago.

I know the correct way of saying is: `The last time I [...] was in October.`

Nevertheless, is `back to` still proper English?

Comment: No, it's not idiomatic. Either *in October* or *back **in** October* is.

Comment: `back in` makes more sense than `back to`. Thank you @JackO'Flaherty!

Comment: As an afterthought, you might say *I have to go back **to** October to find a similar case.*., that is, you might use *back to* along with *go*.

Comment: In that case it's the phrasal verb `go back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's referring to something that happened way back (but with the month), 'back in' is used and not 'to'. Like 'back in the days'...

Comment: Would `back` emphasize the time? because back is optional here.